# MVC2 how is <%: tag different to <%=

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2

what is the difference between <%: and <%= ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that <%: automatically HTML encodes the string whereas <%= does not.

Back before MVC2 came out in order to HTML encode a string you had to use the Html.Encode() method inside the view.

```
<%= Html.Encode(Model.MyString) %>
```

However with MVC2 they added the <%: tag, which outputs the same thing but handles the HTML encoding for you.

```
<%: Model.MyString %>
```

As a rule of thumb you should *always* output your strings using the <%: tag, unless you have a good reason not to.

Checkout [Scott Gu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx) for more information on the subject.

> With ASP.NET 4 we are introducing a
>   new code expression syntax (<%:  %>)
>   that renders output like <%= %> blocks
>   do – but which also automatically HTML
>   encodes it before doing so.  This
>   eliminates the need to explicitly HTML
>   encode content...

Answer (score 3):

Essentially, the `<%:` tag encodes any strings that haven't already been encoded. So:

```
<%: Model.Title %>
```

... is the same as:

```
<%= Server.HtmlEncode(Model.Title ) %>
```

But if you accidentally use the tag where it wasn't necessary:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Title) %>
```

... it will be the same as if you hadn't:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Title) %>
```

See http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx for a full explanation.