# Does Html.LabelFor or Html.TextBoxFor automatically call Html.Encode?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-injection, html.encode

do I still need to call html.ecnode even if I'm only using Html.LabelFor and Html.TextBoxFor or similar function and not using the text directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you calling html.textboxfor  and htmp.textbox in (mvc2)

> ```
>         <%: Html.TextBoxFor(x=> x.MyName) %>
> ```

then no need to call html.encode.

: in <%:  is a html.encode

[SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916386/mvc2-how-is-tag-different-to) for more details