# syntatical difference b/w <%= Html.LabelFor(model=> model.studFatherName) %> and <%: Html.LabelFor(model=> model.studFatherName) %>

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i am bit confuse in the syntax used in mvc.  please tell me what is difference between these two syntax written below :
`<%= Html.LabelFor(model=> model.studFatherName) %>` and
`<%: Html.LabelFor(model=> model.studFatherName) %>`

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC2 how is <%: tag different to <%=](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916386/mvc2-how-is-tag-different-to)

Answer (score 2):

`<%: %>` is used to HTML encode the value whereas `<%= %>` output the value as is. For example:

`<%= "<br/>" %>` is rendered as `<br/>` whereas `<%: %>` is rendered as `&lt;br/&gt;`. There is one exception though. If the argument is an `IHtmlString` then `<%: %>` behaves exactly the same as `<%= %>` i.e. it doesn't encode the value. And since the `LabelFor` helper returns an IHtmlString `<%: Html.LabelFor(x => x.studFatherName) %>` is absolutely equivalent to `<%= Html.LabelFor(x => x.studFatherName) %>`.